# angular 2 / ng-bootstrap: toggle control: read/edit

Tags: angularjs

I have a date-of-birth field that, in read-mode, looks like all my other fields:

```
Name: Bob
DoB: 01/01/1990
```

but when the user clicks on it, it will switch to 3 select fields for editing:

```
Name: Bob
DoB:  [   ] [ ] [    ]
      |Jan|
      |Feb|
```

I can figure out how clicking on the read field converts it to the editable fields, but I'm not sure how to get back. The fields should remain in edit mode as long as the focus is on *any* date field. If you exit all the fields, it should go back to read mode.

```
<div class="form-group with-subtext">
    <input
            type="text"
            name="dob"
            [(ngModel)]="eeLogin.DateOfBirth"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Date of Birth"
            #dob
            required
            (click)="$angular(['DoBMonth']).focus()"
            [class.hidden]="editingDoB" />
    <span
            class="form-inline"
            [class.hidden]="!editingDoB">
        <select name="DoBMonth" [(ngModel)]="DoBMonth" class="form-control" (change)="setDaysThisMonth(DoBMonth);" (focus)="editingDoB=true" (blur)="editingDoB = editingDoB && true">
            <option *ngFor="let month of months" [value]="month.value">
                {{month.display}}
            </option>
        </select>

        <select name="DoBDay" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="DoBDay" (focus)="editingDoB=true" (blur)="editingDoB = editingDoB && true">
            <option *ngFor="let day of days" [value]="day">
                {{day}}
            </option>
        </select>

        <select name="DoBYear" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="DoBYear" (focus)="editingDoB=true" (blur)="editingDoB = editingDoB && true">
            <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">
                {{year}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like a usability nightmare that will piss off all the users of your app. I just wouldn't do that.

Comment: Not a helpful answer.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I posted it as a comment.